# Google Analytics Regex excluding a certain url in a sub folder

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Currently on my GA Account I have the following URL's from our website tracked:

*domain/contact-us/*

*domain/contact-us/global-contact-list.aspx*

*domain/contact-us/contactlist.aspx*

The first two are from our new website which we want to track, the last one is from our old website (traffic is still being tracked but we do not want to use this)

I tried using a regex filter on this as the following:

```
(^/contact-us/global-contact-list\.aspx)|(^/contact-us/)
```

Reading up, I believe this looks for matches of exactly:

*/contact-us/global-contact-list* or */contact us/* but would disallow ***/contact-us/contactlist/***

for some reason, the above one is still coming through. Can someone please see as to why this may be happening or know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a negative look-behind or a end of string anchor:

```
(^/contact-us/global-contact-list\.aspx)|(^/contact-us/$)
```

or

```
(^/contact-us/global-contact-list\.aspx)|(^/contact-us/(?!contactlist/))
```

This way, you will exclude `/contact-us/contactlist/` from matching.

Have a look at the [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/bF2bQ9/1) and [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/bF2bQ9/2).

BTW, `/contact us/` will not pass since `(^/contact-us/)` only allows a hyphen. You should add a space, e.g. `(^/contact-us/global-contact-list\.aspx)|(^/contact[-\s]us/$)`.

Also, `(^/contact-us/global-contact-list\.aspx)` won't match `/contact-us/global-contact-list` because it needs to match `.aspx`.